# Finding posterior mean from prior density

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, bayesian, bayes-theorem

Suppose the probability p of success on an experiment is given a prior with density $f_p(s)=2(1−s) \mathbb{1}_{[0,1]}(s)$. The experiment is independently conducted three times and is a success $N=2$ times.

What is the posterior mean of p?

Does anyone the steps to solving this problem?

Comment: What means II??

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net : it's the indicator function, I suppose

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Yes, it is the indicator function. Sorry, I didn't know how to write it in LaTeK

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.  For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on MathJax notation](/help/notation), [MathJax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/259305) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/290189).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\pi(s|\mathbf{x})\propto (1-s)s^2(1-s)=s^2(1-s)^2$$

That is a $Beta(3;3)$ thus the posterior mean is

$$\mathbb{E}[s|\mathbf{x}]=1/2$$